# ERROR: the "PHPCompatibility" coding standard is not installed

Tags: php, phpcs

When I execute git commit, I get this error:

> ERROR: the "PHPCompatibility" coding standard is not installed. The installed coding standards are MySource, PEAR, Zend, PSR2, PSR1, Squiz, PSR12, Drupal and DrupalPractice
> Fix the PHPCompatibility error before commit please

Then I execute:

```
phpcs --config-set installed_paths vendor/phpcompatibility/php-compatibility
```

Executed git commit again; a new error appeared again:

> ERROR: the "Drupal" coding standard is not installed. The installed coding standards are MySource, PEAR, Zend, PSR2, PSR1, Squiz and PSR12
> Fix the Drupal Standard error before commit please

I executed the command again:

```
phpcs --config-set installed_paths vendor/drupal/coder/coder_sniffer
```

As a result, the original error appeared again:

> the "PHPCompatibility" coding standard is not installed

What's wrong with my configuration?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUly2.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7zyI.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ar4qq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled php_codesniffer and drupal/coder, and executed the command:

```
 phpcs --config-set installed_paths /homeriverz/.config/composer/vendor/phpcompatibility/php-compatibility,/homeriverz/.config/composer/vendor/drupal/coder/coder_sniffer,/homeriverz/.config/composer/vendor/slevomat /coding-standard
```

will run normally

Answer (score 0):

I understand your pre-commit hook launches a linter that requires both standards to be installed simultaneously:

```
phpcs --config-set installed_paths vendor/phpcompatibility/php-compatibility,vendor/drupal/coder/coder_sniffer
```

[Reference](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Configuration-Options#setting-the-installed-standard-paths)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I executed the command:
phpcs --config-set installed_paths vendor/phpcompatibility/php-compatibility,vendor/drupal/coder/coder_sniffer
Refer to the link you gave to configure, but still report an error when executing git commit:
ERROR: the "Drupal" coding standard is not installed. The installed coding standards are MySource, PEAR, Zend, PSR2, PSR1, Squiz and PSR12
Is it my configuration problem? Or the installation of drupal coder? Or is it a version issue?

Comment: What file contains the Drupal standard?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have forgotten to install the package :-)

```
composer require phpcompatibility/php-compatibility --dev
```